# How do you animate text to slide out from an image?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to have text slide out from behind a logo and I'm having some trouble getting the text to smoothly slide out. In this case, I've tried a CSS approach. This snippet shows what kind of animation I'm going for, however, I'm trying to replace the **white line** with **text** while maintaining a smooth transition.

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#444
}

/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
header .logoWrap {
  padding-top:15px;
  width: 40%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
header .logoWrap:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow:0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: flex-grow .6s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}
header .logoWrap:hover:after {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
header .logo {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header .logo img {
  width:70px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logoWrap">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Pepsi-Logo.png" alt="random logo :D"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: is JS and jQuery tag relevant here ? are you looking for a CSS approach or also open to a JS one ?

Comment: CSS, JavaScript... I don't mind. Whichever has the best outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add text inside the content of the pseudo element and animate the `max-width` from 0 to a big value. You need to also set `white-space:nowrap` to keep the text one line and `overflow:hidden` to avoid overflow:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#444
}

/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
header .logoWrap {
  padding-top:15px;
  width: 40%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
header .logoWrap:after {
  content: 'Some text to animate';
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  flex-grow:0;
  max-width:0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .6s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}
header .logoWrap:hover:after {
  max-width:250px;
}
header .logo {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header .logo img {
  width:70px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logoWrap">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="random logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a keyframe (logoAnimation) that animates the movement of the logo. I would also create a new div and place it between the text and the logo, the blocker must be the same colour as the background to create the illusion of the text uncovering, the blocker must also completely block the text at firs. as the logo moves I would also call another keyframe (logoBlockerAnimation) that gets smaller and smaller at the same rate as the logo does

```
@keyframes logoAnimation{
    0%{
     //set the logo start y x position
    }

    100% {
    //set the logo start y x position
    }
}
@keyframes logoBlockerAnimation{
    0%{

     //set the width and x position of the text blocker
    }

    100% {
     //set the width and x position of the text blocker
    }
}
```